# Comparing timestamps in meta query doesn't work

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, query, meta-query

I want to compare two timestamps in a `meta_query` instead of [comparing two dates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/283851/25187) in the "Y-m-d" format, each of them stored separately in custom fields, but no success. The first timestamp is an event start date/time, the second is the local date/time, also as a timestamp. When I use them in my code, posts are displayed in a not understandable order. What is wrong here? The comparison of dates in the "Y-m-d" format works correctly.

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'facebook_events', 'event' ) );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'start_ts', //this is from facebook_events post type
                'value' => current_time( 'timestamp' ),
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_start_ts', //this is from event post type
                'value' => current_time( 'timestamp' ),
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE',
            )
        ) );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the magic: with timestamps, insteed of `'type' => 'DATE'` must be used `'type' => 'NUMERIC'`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! We ran into the same issue and this question helped a lot!

**Alternate Use Case**
We're looping through a custom post type called `events` (*surprise, surprise, it stores events*). It stores a timestamp in the meta field `ev_start` (*event start time*). We actually were able to just use the orderby value `meta_value_num` (*as you can see meta_type is commented out*). We also query the posts to make sure the event didn't already happen.

```
$current_time = current_time('timestamp');

$post_args = array(
   'post_type'         => 'events',
   'posts_per_page'    => 5, 
   'meta_key'          => 'ev_start',
   //'meta_type'       => 'NUMERIC',
   'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num', 
   'order'             => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
         'key'     => 'ev_start',
         'value'   => $current_time,
         'compare' => '>='
      )
   )
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $post_args );
```

**Resources**
[WP_Query Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)